# Como arrumar URL amigável?

Tags: htaccess, joomla, url-amigável

Eu fiz a migração do meu site Joomla pra outro servidor mas ele só está funcionando a Home, as páginas internas dão erro 404. Eu ja ativei/desativei a opção de URL amigável no Joomla, vi o htaccess também e nada funcionou. Estou usando o htaccess padrão do Joomla:

```htaccess
##
 # @version $Id: htaccess.txt 10492 2008-07-02 06:38:28Z ircmaxell $
 # @package Joomla
 # @copyright Copyright (C) 2005 - 2008 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
 # @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU/GPL
 # Joomla! is Free Software
 ##


 #####################################################
 #  READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE
 #
 # The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
 # with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
 # be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
 # your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
 # beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
 # it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
 #
 #####################################################

 ##  Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
 Options +FollowSymLinks

 #
 #  mod_rewrite in use

 RewriteEngine On

 ########## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
 ## If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
 ## This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
 #
 # Block out any script trying to set a mosConfig value through the URL
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
 # Block out any script trying to base64_encode crap to send via URL
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
 # Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
 # Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
 # Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
 # Send all blocked request to homepage with 403 Forbidden error!
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
 #
 ########## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits

 #  Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
 #  is not directly related to physical file paths.
 #  Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root)

 # RewriteBase /


 ########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
 #
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
 RewriteRule (.*) index.php
 RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
 #
 ########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section
```

http://docs.joomla.org/Preconfigured_htaccess

Comment: http://docs.joomla.org/Preconfigured_htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você deve renomear o arquivo htaccess.txt para .htaccess, e ir nas configurações (SEO Settings) e marcar sim para as duas primeiras opções.